# can not remove a trend components and a seasonal components

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am trying to make a model for predicting energy production, by using ARMA model.

The data I can use for training is as following;

（https://github.com/soma11soma11/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge/blob/master/challenge1/data/training_dataset_500.csv）

```
ID  Label   House   Year    Month   Temperature Daylight    EnergyProduction
0     0       1     2011     7         26.2      178.9         740
1     1       1     2011     8         25.8      169.7         731
2     2       1     2011     9         22.8      170.2         694
3     3       1     2011     10        16.4      169.1         688
4     4       1     2011     11        11.4      169.1         650
5     5       1     2011     12         4.2      199.5         763
...............

11995 19     500    2013     2          4.2      201.8         638
11996 20     500    2013     3         11.2        234         778
11997 21     500    2013     4         13.6      237.1         758
11998 22     500    2013     5         19.2      258.4         838
11999 23     500    2013     6         22.7      122.9         586
```

As shown above, I can use data from July 2011 to May 2013 for training.
Using the training, I want to predict energy production on June 2013 for each 500 house.

The problem is that the time series data is not stationary and has trend components and seasonal components (I checked it as following.).

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data_train = pd.read_csv('../../data/training_dataset_500.csv')

rng=pd.date_range('7/1/2011', '6/1/2013', freq='M')
house1 = data_train[data_train.House==1][['EnergyProduction','Daylight','Temperature']].set_index(rng)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
for i, column in enumerate(house1.columns):
    house1[column].plot(ax=axes[i], figsize=(14,3), title=column)

plt.show()
```

[image]

With this data, I cannot implement ARMA model to get good prediction. So I want to get rid of the trend components and a seasonal components and make the time series data stationary. I tried this problem, but I could not remove these components and make it stationary..

Comment: this *not* an answer, but ARMA models are implemented in the statsmodels library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the Hodrick-Prescott (HP) filter, which is widely used in macroeconometrics to separate long-term trending component from short-term fluctuations. It is implemented `statsmodels.api.tsa.filters.hpfilter`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('/home/Jian/Downloads/data.csv', index_col=[0])

# get part of the data
x = df.loc[df.House==1, 'Daylight']
# hp-filter, set parameter lamb=129600 following the suggestions for monthly data
x_smoothed, x_trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(x, lamb=129600)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4), ncols=3)
axes[0].plot(x)
axes[0].set_title('raw x')
axes[1].plot(x_trend)
axes[1].set_title('trend')
axes[2].plot(x_smoothed)
axes[2].set_title('smoothed x')
```

[image]

Comment: With your code, I can successfully removed trend compmonents!! thnaks!

But how to remove seasonal components!?

Comment: Hi! Jianxun! Thanks for answering the question! But I cannot apply this to my code... I posted another question.. It would be great if you could please check it..